# How do you count functions in a finite set?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

[image]

So, I'm trying to get a head start on learning discrete mathematics, but for all my reading I have absolutely no real idea on how to approach these types of questions. As far as I'm aware, I thought I need to multiply for every possible image, so (1) was $5^5$, but apparently its $5^4$?? I'm just really confused and I'd appreciate it if someone was able to point me in the right direction for these problems.

Comment: The answer to (1) is $5^4$ because $1$ is already mapped to $2$ - so you have only $4$ elements left to map $\{2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and the range $B$ still has 5 elements.

Comment: A similar analysis works for (2), though you do need to consider what $f(1)$ can be. (3) and (4) are similar, except the onto condition changes how you count possible functions. For (5) and (6), I suggest you start experimenting, "if $f(1) = 2$, then what can $f(2)$ be?" Also remember that saying two functions are the same requires them to have the same value for *every* argument.